# Duda con "Back Button" en Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para Android e iOS con Xamarin Forms. Entonces, cuando abro una nueva página lo hago de la siguiente manera: 
`var newPage = new ContentPage (); await Navigation.PushAsync (newPage);` 
Mi duda es: Al presionar el botón "Back Button" (Ya sea el botón físico del dispositivo o el qué se encuentra en la barra de navegación) la página se elimina completamente de la navegación o queda en la caché?

Answer (score 1):

La pagina se elimina. Si quieres volver a la pagina vas a tener que crear otro objeto nuevamente.

Comment: Para realizar respuestas es importante leer [answer].